# Port Collision Between Apache2 and Httpd2

Tags: port

How do I prevent port collision between apache2 and httpd2? I start apache2 and says the port is already in use. I have to modify the httpd.conf to get http2 working.

Comment: Use different ports for 2 servers. Check conf files. Other than port 80, port 8080 is also a commonly used http port. You would obviously need to use `http://server-name:8080` for that...

Comment: But httpd.config seems to be used for both, or should I change the port.conf file for apache2?

Comment: ^^ Oh... I didn't know that... See if you can change the conf file name for one of the servers. Or any command line parameter for one of them...

Comment: Why do you need both? Apache2 and httpd2 are the same thing - just some distros call it one or the other. So why not move everything into one (latest) version?

Comment: They apparently aren't the same thing because you can run Apache and not run httpd and the website won't show up. Both need to be running.